# how to iterate over string and capture specific fields from string

Tags: bash, shell, key-value

I am working on script that will capture specific fields from below string.
can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

Want to capture QUEUE name which is SYSTEM.RETAINED.PUB.QUEUE, DEPTH, CURFSIZE etc.

data-
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2022. Starting MQSC for queue manager TESTQMGR. 1 : dis qs(SYSTEM.RETAINED.PUB.QUEUE) AMQ8450I: Display queue status details. QUEUE(SYSTEM.RETAINED.PUB.QUEUE) TYPE(QUEUE) CURDEPTH(56) CURFSIZE(1) CURMAXFS(2088960) IPPROCS(0) LGETDATE(2023-03-09) LGETTIME(09.44.40) LPUTDATE(2023-03-09) LPUTTIME(09.44.40) MEDIALOG( ) MONQ(MEDIUM) MSGAGE(3620167) OPPROCS(0) QTIME(1578, 1578)

Comment: What programming language do you work with?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve the problem. Two examples:

**pure bash**

```
string='data- 5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2022. Starting MQSC for queue manager TESTQMGR. 1 : dis qs(SYSTEM.RETAINED.PUB.QUEUE) AMQ8450I: Display queue status details. QUEUE(SYSTEM.RETAINED.PUB.QUEUE) TYPE(QUEUE) CURDEPTH(56) CURFSIZE(1) CURMAXFS(2088960) IPPROCS(0) LGETDATE(2023-03-09) LGETTIME(09.44.40) LPUTDATE(2023-03-09) LPUTTIME(09.44.40) MEDIALOG( ) MONQ(MEDIUM) MSGAGE(3620167) OPPROCS(0) QTIME(1578, 1578)'

[[ $string =~    QUEUE\(([^\)]*) ]]; queue=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
[[ $string =~ CURDEPTH\(([^\)]*) ]]; depth=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
[[ $string =~ CURFSIZE\(([^\)]*) ]]; crfsz=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

declare -p queue depth crfsz
```

**bash + GNU grep**

```
string='data- 5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2022. Starting MQSC for queue manager TESTQMGR. 1 : dis qs(SYSTEM.RETAINED.PUB.QUEUE) AMQ8450I: Display queue status details. QUEUE(SYSTEM.RETAINED.PUB.QUEUE) TYPE(QUEUE) CURDEPTH(56) CURFSIZE(1) CURMAXFS(2088960) IPPROCS(0) LGETDATE(2023-03-09) LGETTIME(09.44.40) LPUTDATE(2023-03-09) LPUTTIME(09.44.40) MEDIALOG( ) MONQ(MEDIUM) MSGAGE(3620167) OPPROCS(0) QTIME(1578, 1578)'

queue=$(echo "$string" | grep -zPo    'QUEUE\(\K[^)]*')
depth=$(echo "$string" | grep -zPo 'CURDEPTH\(\K[^)]*')
crfsz=$(echo "$string" | grep -zPo 'CURFSIZE\(\K[^)]*')

declare -p queue depth crfsz
```